# how to exclude Vertex which does not contain a value

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am using AWS Neptune gremlin, I have a vertex with a property stored multiple values

Vertex label 'apple' with property color, e.g. created a 'apple' vertex with property color multiple values ['red', 'white']

`g.V().hasLabel('apple').has('color', TextP.notContaining('wh'))`

the problem is it still returns this vertex, how can I exclude the V that contains 'wh'?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by using `not` step:

```
g.V().hasLabel('apple').not(has('color', containing('wh')))
```

Your query filters the vertices only if all the colors values don't contains 'wh'

with `not` and `containing` you can filter if one or more values contain 'wh'.

example: https://gremlify.com/85

Comment: While `not()` traversal step works in this case, graph providers may return a more optimized result from the `notContaining()` predicate which is more concise.

Comment: @stephenmallette Makes sense .. How would you solve it with `notContaining` ?

Comment: sorry - you're right. i misread the question/answer a bit. i guess i would do a straight `notContaining` first to try to ensure an index hit then follow with a filter that would likely end up in-memory with `not()` step as you have it. i suppose it's all specific to the provider at that point to figure out what you should do. Doing "not" never seems nice for Gremlin. I guess I'd `profile()` and see what i ended up with. Anyway, your answer is the most direct I'd say and the best place to start. My comments might just be noise at this point. :/

Comment: @noam621, I have a further question, is it possible we can apply multiple condition against same value in the property values array? e.g. what if I want to exclude the items (starting with 'wh' and containing 'e' and other item does not contain 'e' neither), e.g. ['fff','whe'] should be excluded, but ['red','whfff'], ['red','white''] need to be included.), to make it simple, I only want to get the result that the 1st value in the array contains 'e'

Comment: @Zhongmin you can do something like that: https://gremlify.com/8a ... but at this point, it seems not optimized at all. maybe you should consider splitting the colors to different vertices and connect them by an edge to your main vertex.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, as per gremlin 3.6 is:

```
%%gremlin -p v,ine,outv,oute,inv,oute,inv
g.V().hasLabel('apple').not(has('color','wh')).outE().inV().path().by(valueMap()).limit(5)
```